# Avoid other Android Apps to listen my broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-permissions

Well... I don't know if trying to do this has sense on Android Architecture or if is even possible.

I accept 3rd party Apps to call my App through a BroadcastReceiver with a custom intent-filter. So, I ask for 3rd party Apps to send me the package name to be able to send them, through sendBroadcast, callbacks about the status of the work delegated on me.

Now, I want to make my own 3rd party App that connects with my core App and I'm worried that some special callbacks will be sent and capture only by my 3rd party App.

So, if an "unauthorized" 3rd party listen for the intent filter that I send will catch my Broadcast.

Currently, when I receive the Broadcast of my own 3rd party, I check the package name and check if this package is installed to try to avoid that non authorized fake to identify as my own 3rd party. But if user has my 3rd party installed and the non authorized, this "protection" will fail.

I read a bit about sett custom permissions, but I don't know if will fit in my scenario.

Could you give me some advices?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `signature`-level permissions, per Mighter's answer, may be a solution, though beware that [there are issues with custom permissions as well](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/02/12/vulnerabilities-custom-permissions.html). Another approach would be for you to not have the clients send you a package name, but instead send you a `PendingIntent`, into which you merge any new/changed extras when you run it. This should allow your own client to use a non-exported `BroadcastReceiver` as the means for your app to send callbacks.

Comment: Woah! I read the article about security and I got shocked. I don't know how to do the approach with PendingIntents, I use them only to use Notifications and... are a bit confusing ^^. I'll investigate further to see if match with my scenario, thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare finally I use a PendingIntent architecture, if you add an answer proposing that solution I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PendingIntent` has an interesting property: not only does it bundle up an `Intent` and the operation to be performed upon it, but it also effectively bundles up the security context in which that operation is performed.

In other words, it can be used to allow a foreign process to talk to one of your components, even if that component is not exported.

We see this a lot in standard uses of `PendingIntent`, such a `AlarmManager` or `Notification`. We usually use an explicit `Intent` inside the `PendingIntent` (e.g., `new Intent(this, MyOtherComponent.class)`). And usually those components do not have an `<intent-filter>` or are otherwise exported in our manifest. Yet, they work. That's because while the OS process that manages alarms and/or notifications does not have the right to talk to our component normally, it can execute the `PendingIntent`, and the `PendingIntent` is our way of saying "yes, you can talk to this component, but only for whatever this `PendingIntent` does, not arbitrary stuff".

So, if one app wants to set up a callback mechanism with another app, a slick approach is to use a `PendingIntent`. The first app's component (e.g., `BroadcastReceiver`) does not have to be exported, let alone have an `<intent-filter>`. Yet, the second app can trigger that component via the `PendingIntent`. Since a `PendingIntent` is `Parcelable`, it can be packaged easily enough as an extra on some other `Intent`, passed via an AIDL-defined interface for a bound service, or otherwise traverse process boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom permission with security level "signature", then only the apps which are signed with the same key will be able to send broadcasts to your receiver. 
If that solves your problem, you're fine.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel

> "signature" -     A permission that the system grants only if the
>   requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the
>   application that declared the permission. If the certificates match,
>   the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the
>   user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

Comment: my apps will need share package name or some shareId configuration in manifest? I mean because the core App is already published and it's too late to fix that u__u

Comment: The only thing that matters is a private key which you use to sign your released apk.

Comment: I see, but then while I'm on development process without signed Apps I can't test it properly, isn't? I mean, I need to trust in that permission and "deactivate" while developing...

Comment: I'm not sure, but AFAIK while developing, all your apps are signed with debug certificate, which is unique for your machine. So it still should be the same for 2 apps.

Comment: @rubdottocom: The signing key issue becomes somewhat easier if you can move to Gradle for your build system. Gradle for Android makes it easy for you to have different package names for production (e.g., `com.app`) and debug (e.g., `com.app.debug`) builds. This allows both to be installed at the same time on the same device, so you can test a debug client with a debug app while not disturbing a copy of the production app also installed on the test environment.